# How to display only some characters from a string with multiple consecutive characters?

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have this string: `fffooooobbbbaarrr`.
Given a number N, for each duplicated characters, I want to display N of them.

If N=2, the output is `ffoobbaarr`

If N=3, the output is `fffooobbbaarrr`

If N=1, the output is `fobar`

And if N=0, the output is  (empty)

As I'm learning regex, after some experimentation, I found that this works for N=2:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1{2,}");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(input.replaceAll("$1$1"));
```

Of course, won't work for N=3, 4, etc.
How to fix this?

Comment: Use https://ideone.com/NX2oUW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that solution fails with `0`

Comment: @YCF_L No one wants to remove 0 chars from a string, that is not logical. If one wants to remove any word chars, there is a simple `.replaceAll("\\w+", "")`, no need to invent complex patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP is clear **And if N=0, the output is  (empty)**

Comment: @YCF_L I doubt it is that clear. anta, what about `More text, and fffooooobbbbaarrr here.` string? What output do you expect with `N=0` and `N=2`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it should be `More text, and ffoobbaarr here.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If `N=0`, well the output is of course empty string. And if `N=2`, @YCF_L got it right :)

Comment: Then you have anubhava's and revo's answers that should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex replacement:

```
int n = 3 // or whatever number;
String repl = "";

if (n > 0) {
   repl = str.replaceAll("((\\S)\\2{" + (n-1) + "})\\2*", "$1");
}
```

**Example: (for N=3)**

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/BpS9Zm/1)

**Example: (for N=2)**

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BpS9Zm/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1
- `(\S)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace char and capture as group #2
- `\2{2}`: Match 2 instances of same char
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\2*`: Match 0+ instances of same character outside capture group

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/GxPgjL)

Comment: I think you got a downvote for using `\1` replacement, use `$1`. Besides, note that `n` should probably be `n-1` and `\\2+` should be `\\2*`.

Comment: You are completely right @WiktorStribiżew. I don't know what I was thinking when I used `\\1` instead of `$1` in replacement in Java (sorry for being silly). And yes it should be `n-1` as I had in my regex demo also.

Comment: Yeah, and I think it is easier to use a simple `if` check to return an empty string if N=0. Although I start to doubt I understand OP logic.

Comment: Check now: https://ideone.com/GxPgjL It should be `System.out.println(repl);` instead of `System.out.println(str);`

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: Oh np at all, and thank for preparing a code demo (part of answer now)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Man regex is pretty complicated O__o

Answer (score 1):

Use below regex as looker:

```
(\\w)(\\1{N})\\1*
```

Breakdown:

- `(\w)` Match and capture a letter to capturing group 1
- `(\1{N})` Match previous captured letter `N` times (capturing group 2)
- `\1*` Match any number of following repetitions

**N** is the number of letters you need to retain (you could use it as a variable. `0` results an empty output) and for replacement use:

```
$2
```

[Regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPjk9z/1)

Java code ([demo](https://ideone.com/S7Lez2)):

```
String str = "fffooooobbbbaarrr";
int N = 3;
str = str.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\1{" + N + "})\\1*", "$2");
System.out.println(str); // fffooobbbaarrr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Pattern and matcher like this :

```
    String text = "fffooooobbbbaarrr";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    String result = "";
    int len = 3;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if(matcher.group().length() >= len) {
            result += matcher.group().substring(0, len);
        }else {
            result += matcher.group();
        }

    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Result :

```
3 --> fffooobbbaarrr
2 --> ffoobbaarr
1 --> fobar
0 --> empty
```

---

The idea is :

- match any repetitive character `(.)\1*` zero or more time
- then check if the length of that matches is great or equal to your length, if so use substring to get the length you want.
- else use the matched characters as it is.